# Stumped on Just 0 return

Tags: haskell, encode

Ok, slight edit as the example `encode 99 18 108 45 = Nothing` was actually correct and apparently I can't read questions properly, as 99 and 18 aren't prime, so I added a check funct into the code:

```
coprime :: Int -> Int -> Bool
coprime a b = gcd a b == 1

check :: Int -> Int -> Bool
check p q = (isPrime p) && (isPrime q)

phi :: Int -> Int -> Int
phi p q = (p - 1) * (q - 1)

encrypt :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
encrypt p q m e = powmod m e (p * q)

encode :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
encode p q m e |check p q && coprime (phi p q) e = Just (encrypt p q m e)
           |otherwise = Nothing
```

This time around my problem seems to be `encode 53 73 151 90 = Just 133` 
but the example says it should return `Just 3869` rather than `Just 133`.

So my question to you guys is: am I just being an idiot and not seeing the fault right in front of me or is my working ok?

I'll put `isPrime` code up if you want as well, however it just checks whether a no. is prime or not by returning true or false.

Comment: Is it possible to show the sample input that returns `Just 0` where it should return `Nothing`?

Comment: encode 99 18 108 45 returns Just 0, encode 37 17 23 48 returns Nothing

Comment: I would guess this has to do with the power. You can not calculate powers modulo a number with `Int`, those numbers are too large, and will result in overflow.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you're having, what's the type of `(== True)`? How would you characterize the way it transforms its input? Why do you think I'm asking those questions?

Comment: Consider changing all `Int` values to `Integer`.

Comment: Only problem is that I'm not allowed to changed the signature for encode and I'm not allowed to import anything

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: this will result in a huge memory (and CPU) burden.

Comment: There are smart expmod implementations that could fix the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you raise numbers to a *large* power, which results in *very* large numbers, and `Int` usually contains up to 64-bit numbers. As a result, we get overflow, and the CPU will perform a wrap around.

It is usually *not* a good idea to calcuate *a<sup>b</sup>* mod *c* by calculating the formula directly. We can use a more clever approach here: since *(a×b)* mod *c == ((a* mod *c) × (b* mod *c))* mod *c*, we can exploit this property by calculating the power in such way that we require a minimal amount of memory:

```
powmod :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
powmod _ 0 _ = 1
powmod a b c | even b = ab2
             | otherwise = mod (a * ab2) c
    where ab2 = powmod (mod (a * a) c) (div b 2) c
```

So here we calculate in *O(log b)* (with *b* the *value* the power) *a<sup>b</sup>* mod *c*, where *a<sup>b</sup>* itself can be very large by performing modulo operations at all recursion levels. We here make the assumption that `c` is smaller than the square root of the maximum value of `Int`. Since an `Int` at least has a minimum upper bound of *2<sup>29</sup>-1*, this means that it works as long as c ≤ 23'170. In case you need a function that works with higher values, then you better use `Int64` (max value for `c` is 3'037'000'499) or `Integer` (arbitrary maximum value).

Now we can use this function for the `encrypt` function:

```
encrypt :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
encrypt p q m e = powmod m e (p * q)
```

Your `encode` function can however be improved. You use `== True`, which is unnecessary, since `True == True` is `True`, and `False == True` is `False`.

```
encode :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
encode p q m e | coPrime (phi p q) e = Just (encrypt p q m e)
               |otherwise = Nothing
```

Now we get:

```
Prelude> encode 99 18 108 45
Just 1134
Prelude> encode 37 17 23 48
Nothing
```

Comment: @C.Brandani: well you can check it here https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~jpopyack/IntroCS/HW/RSAWorksheet.html (`p=99`, `q=18`, `m=108`, `e=45`, `d=1629`).

Comment: Be aware, though, that for large inputs, `*` itself is susceptible to overflow. You either need to be very careful, or just lift the arguments to `Integer` until you get the final answer and convert that to an `Int` to return.